# Simple Sql Procedure with/without cursor

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Please help me with a simple procedure, lets say on Sql Server (2005, 2008, does not matter).

I have table `dbo.[columns] with 1000 lines`, which all are the names for some specific table names from a database.

Bottom line is that I need to create a procedure which will parse all 1000 lines of tables,
for each table name found in dbo.[columns] to execute the following

```
select: select count(*), ''''+[column_name]+'''' from dbo.[column_name]
```

The result should be like this:

```
count(*)    table_name:
100          employees 
0            ex_employees
25           addresses
10           birthdays
```

Any hints?

Thanks in advance,
Bogdan

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT  COUNT(Column_With_List_Of_Table_Names_Here)
        , Column_With_List_Of_Table_Names_Here
FROM    YourDatabase.dbo.YourTable
GROUP BY Column_With_List_Of_Table_Names_Here;
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not what are you asking, but should get the results I think you want. You can use system views to get the row count for each table without running `COUNT(*)`

```
SELECT i.rowcnt, o.name FROM sysindexes i
LEFT JOIN sys.objects o ON i.id = o.object_id
WHERE indid <2
ORDER BY name
```

or

```
SELECT SUM (row_count) AS ROWS, o.Name AS TableName
FROM sys.dm_db_partition_stats s
LEFT JOIN sys.objects o ON s.object_id = o.object_id AND (index_id=0 or index_id=1)
GROUP BY o.Name
```

*2nd query should be more precise

Inner joining this queries to your `dbo.[columns]` can filter the results only for your desired tables.

Answer (score 0):

Try this using `CURSOR`  And [Dynamic sql](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20815/Building-Dynamic-SQL-In-a-Stored-Procedure)

```
CREATE TABLE #temp(count_ int,table_name varchar(50))
DECLARE @column_Name VARCHAR(50)
DECLARE @query VARCHAR(500)

  DECLARE table_cursor CURSOR FOR
  SELECT [column_name] from dbo.[column_name]
  OPEN product_cursor
    FETCH NEXT FROM product_cursor INTO @column_Name

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN

    SET @query='INSERT INTO #temp SELECT'+ @column_Name+',COUNT(*) FROM'+  @column_Name

    EXEC sp_executesql @SQLStatement=@query
    /*this will insert the coresponding table name and its row count to #temp*/

    END

    CLOSE product_cursor
    DEALLOCATE product_cursor


select  * from #temp
```